# Better "if statement" structure

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm setting up a spacing structure for some text on an image. So I have to set a $s value for every letter of the alphabet (lower and uppercase) so that is 52 statements.

If I go this route the elseif statement list is going to be huge...

Is there a better way to do this to help shorten the code that finds the $s value depending on the $char value?

Thank you.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what is inside the if statements.  Post some code.  You may be able to do a large SWITCH statement; or you may be able to use the int value of the character to do some math without an IF or SWITCH..

Comment: Could you show the code, either here or on a Github Gist (or similar), to demonstrate what it is you're having trouble with? I don't think 52 statements is the way to go... sounds more like a Switch/Case would work here, or looking up the spacing in a 52-element array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an associative array:

```
$map = array('a' => 'value', 'b' => 'other value', ...);
$char = 'a';
$settingForChar = $map[$char]; // value
```

Comment: Here is some [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are hoping to accomplish, but couldn't you just use a monospace font, or is that not an option here?  Then you know the spacing, it's the same for every character.